# Weird horizontal offset on Notes Client form

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a weird offset happening on some forms which I observed at a customer's computer. Happens for all newly composed documents.

I've looked at the tabs and margins within the form but could find nothing amiss.

Anybody have an idea of the cause?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this before, but could never figure it out. I had to re-create a new form from scratch to fix it.  IIRC, I first tried cutting and pasting the whole form design, and the new form had the same problem, so I had to cut and paste it piece by piece and test it every step of the way to be sure I hadn't picked up whatever it was that was causing the problem.

Comment: I am quite sure, that in one single line of the form the left border is smaller than 1“ (2.54 cm). Then the form „runs away“ like this. Check every left border ( of course only of the outermost elements, not within tables)

Comment: Hi Torsten, I found the culprit. There was one table which went beyond 1". I corrected it. If you post this as an answer, I'll credit you.

Comment: The weird thing is that it happened only on one machine. It could be a difference in Notes Client version?